# LSTM prediction restriction

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

Is it possible to restrict the prediction of LSTM neural network to a `finite set` of values? For example if I have the following sequence `1,4,5,3,2,1,3,2, ...` and I know that the next value will be in the `set {1,2,3,4,5}`, is it possible to feed that somehow to the network so it will always output one of these values?

Comment: you mean randomly one of this values?

Comment: Hi @RafaelDouradoD. The data is periodic, so I expect it will not be random. I trained the network with a periodic data containing values from this set. However, when I use the test set for prediction the network outputs values which are not in this set.

Comment: Because regression predicions are continuous values, even if your labels are in a discrete (limited) range, it is not guaranteed the prediction will.
If you want your predictions be exactly some discrete value, you should transform your regression problem into a classification problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is technically possible (you would have to write your own LSTM implementation or extend the existing one, however), it doesn't seem like a good approach towards this problem. If you find yourself in the situation where you're feeding data to the network that you don't want it to process, you should just preprocess your input to only hold relevant data.

**Show the network what you want it to see.** If you want the network to output specific behavior in certain situations, you can encode that behavior by modifying the labels to reflect this behavior. Finally, note that your use case suggests that you should be working with categorical labels and softmax output, i.e. framing this as a classification instead of a regression problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will create a multi-class LSTM classification to check the prediction performance.